# How is Riesz Lemma "a substitute for orthogonality"?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

I been reading the lemma and some consequences but cant figure out why whats stated in the wikipedia aritcle is true. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma

Comment: The classic application of this lemma is to prove that the closed unit ball is *not* compact in infinite-dimensional normed spaces (without using an inner product).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, where You have the notion of orthogonality, for a closed convex subset $U$ You can always find an orthogonal projection $P:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow U$ such that

$||\phi-P\phi||=dist(\phi,U)$ for all $\phi\in \mathcal{H}\backslash U$.

but You need the parallelogramm identity at some point to see that the infimum is taken by an element. In general Banach spaces $X$ the best You can achieve for a closed real subspace $U$ is to find an "almost orthogonal" element $\phi_{\theta}$ so that

$||\phi-\phi_{\theta}||\leq\frac{1}{\theta}dist(\phi,U)$

and this leads to Riesz´s lemma: $\psi_{\theta}=\frac{\phi-\phi_{\theta}}{||\phi-\phi_{\theta}||}$ for some $\phi \in X \backslash U$ is such an element, whose existence is the statement of the lemma.

Comment: You have $\phi \in U$ initially and at the end you have $\phi \in X - U$.

Comment: @csss Thanks. I hope it´s correct now.