# Proving orthogonality properties of residuals for $L^p$ optimization

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization, vector-spaces

Consider an $L^2$ (also called least-squares) optimization problem over a vector space $V$, in which one is trying to minimize the $L^2$-norm of the difference between some "target" vector $y$ and vectors in some subspace $W$ of $V$. (This "difference vector" is often called the residual vector.)

The Hilbert projection theorem guarantees that there is a unique vector $x$ in $W$ that minimizes the norm of this residual vector, and consequently also guarantees that the residual vector $x - y$ is orthogonal to the subspace $W$.

If I consider the same problem, but with the key difference that I now want to minimize a $L^{p\neq2}$ norm of the residual, I can provably lose uniqueness of the optimizing vector $x$ (certainly the case in $L^{1}$).

However, I don't know if you also lose orthogonality of the residual vector w.r.t. the subspace $W$, and for which $L^p$ spaces this occurs. **Is there a way to show that the residual for such an optimization problem is/isn't orthogonal to the subspace $W$ for the cases where $L^{p\neq2}$?**

Comment: You don't exactly  need a notion of orthogonality. It is enough to require that the ball of the $L^p$ space is "convex enough". If you choose $p \in (1,\infty)$ you can use Clarckson's inequalities for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research, I can answer this question. I will leave it up in case this can potentially help anyone.

The first thing is that the notion of orthogonality for $L^{p\neq2}$ is not well-defined; the fact that $L^2$ is a Hilbert space is basically needed in order to be able to define such a property. And if one tried to measure $L^2$ orthogonality of a residual obtained from an $L^{p\neq2}$ optimization problem, it would never be able to be orthogonal unless the $L^{p\neq2}$ optimization problem was identical to its $L^2$ equivalent due to the uniqueness result of the Hilbert projection theorem.

However, one can get *close* to a definition of orthogonality in normed vector spaces that aren't Hilbert spaces by using [Riesz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz's_lemma), and the way in which this lemma is useful for describing "almost orthogonal" functions has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440029/how-is-riesz-lemma-a-substitute-for-orthogonality).